# django rest api: JSON parse error - No JSON object could be decoded

Tags: json, django, api, rest

I'm using postman to create a POST request to my django view

```
@csrf_exempt
@api_view(['POST'])
def create_user(request):
    data = JSONParser().parse(request)
    serializer = CaretakerSerializer(data=data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return JSONResponse(serializer.data, status=201)
    return JSONResponse(serializer.errors, status=400)
```

but I get the following error:

```
{
  "detail": "JSON parse error - No JSON object could be decoded"
}
```

When trying to print my request.body I get the following:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryrg1JNLvBOEfjkQAT
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name"

Rubencito
------WebKitFormBoundaryrg1JNLvBOEfjkQAT
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="email"

rubencito@yahoo.com
------WebKitFormBoundaryrg1JNLvBOEfjkQAT--
```

This is the postman screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well you are not sending json, you are sending regular POST request with name/value pairs.

You need to switch postman to "raw" format and type something like `{"name": "X", "email":"Y"}`

Then on a python side you can read it as `json.loads(request.body)`

Comment: How can we get form-data in django view?